# Saved string as doc from data of html presentation of 'NSAttributedString' with image attachment can not show image

Tags: swift, macos

I am creating an `NSMutableAttributedString`, attaching an image, getting string value from html representation and saving it, found from SO answer. It can get the relative file path on string. But If I save it as doc file it does not show image. Probably doc software can not find that location and doc's should not dynamically load data from file location. Is there any way to embed image while saving as doc file?

Heres what I'm doing:

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    // create our NSTextAttachment
    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "red-roses.jpg") //NSIMage 

    // wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

    // add the NSTextAttachment wrapper to our full string, then add some more text.
    fullString.append(image1String)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

    // draw the result in a label
    label.attributedText = fullString
    
    print(fullString.mutableString)
    //imageView.image = UIImage(named: "red-roses")
    
    do {
                let htmlData = try fullString.data(from: .init(location: 0, length: fullString.length),
                                                       documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html])
                let htmlString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
                print(htmlString)
    //try htmlString.writeTo(fileLocation, "filename.doc")
     } catch {
         print(error)
     }
```

It can show relative file path on `htmlString`. The saved doc will show only strings and no image. Is there any way to embed image on doc?

Comment: You can not embed an image inside a html file. It is just a String. Your only option is to convert your image data to base64EncodedString

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @LeoDabus The saved docx doesn't show the image from embedded string as base64 encoded and opening the app does not show any image, only text.

Comment: You won't be able to do that using the method above. You will need to manually replace the image inside your html

Comment: How can I show embedded image in html saved as doc/docx?

Comment: you need to replace `<img src="file:///Attachment.png" alt="Attachment.png">` by `<img src="data:image/png;base64,THEIMAGEBASE64STRINGGOESHERE" alt="Image Alternative Text" />` in your html string. don't forget to use jpg instead of png

Comment: I have tested in similar way. I saved an html document directly with solution from [this answer]( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/7291498). Saved as docx. opened in wpf app and no image appeared, but text appeared. Image appears on webpage on a browser but same code as a doc no image on wpf mac app.

Comment: DocX is a xml not a html

Comment: Not related to your question but why did you tag this as macOS and are trying to embed an UIImage instead of NSImage?

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm testing that on iOS with `UIKit`, tested same for macOS with `AppKit`, so I hinted `NSImage`. I did not tag for iOS but I think similar operation applies for both.

Comment: From [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1271014/How-to-convert-base64-imgae-as-HTML-text-to-word-d), I'm taking result that doc can not show embedded images data/Base64Image.